# What's the probability of getting a prime number by typing randomly a number which length's is 8 digits?

Tags: probability

What's the probability of getting a prime number by typing randomly a number which length's is 8 digits?

I've typed randomly 90,873,479 and discovered it was prime. I had only 1 try, what was the probability of getting a prime number in this case? (8 digits long number)

Comment: how many prime numbers are 8 digits long?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 5096876 primes between 10000000 and 99999999. That is a fraction of 5.6%

A more general result is given by the [prime number theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem): It says (roughly) that the probability that a random number lower than $n$ is close to $1/\ln(n)$

In this case $n = 10^8$, so the probability is roughly $1/\ln(10^8) = 0.054$, so not far off indeed.

Comment: Presumably the digits 0 count as well, so you need to count all primes from 00000000 to 99999999.

Comment: In that case there are $4+21+143+1061+8363+68906+586081+5096876=5761455$ primes with 8 or fewer digits, giving a probability of $0,0576$.

Comment: I am curious why you ignored primes less than 10000000? Presumably initial zeros are just as likely?

Comment: You could argue that numbers less than 10000000 are not 8-digit numbers.

Comment: Yes, but the original poster claimed that he just spammed 8 digits. Which might as well have been "00000001" (not considering the human mind, for a second).

Comment: He asks about "... by typing randomly a number which length's is 8 digits", $00000001 = 1$ is not really a number with a length of 8 digits. It's just a matter of how you interpret the question, and not very interesting at all.

Answer (score 1):

There are 5761455 primes between 00000000 and 99999999. This gives the probability
as ${5761455 \over 10^8} \approx 0.0576$.

(I counted using [this](https://primes.utm.edu/lists/small/millions/) page.)

Comment: Shouldn't we divide 5761455 by (10^9)-1? Instead of 10^8

Comment: No, it is an eight digit string, each of which can have 10 possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

The number of primes less than *n* is called the [*`π function`*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function):

According to [*https://primes.utm.edu/nthprime/*](https://primes.utm.edu/nthprime/), there are 5,761,455 primes less than or equal to 99,999,999, and 664,579 primes less than or equal to 10,000,000 (=5,096,876). Which means that the probability of you hitting one of them is 5096876/89999999 = 0.05663196185...

**That is, ~5.66% - or about one out of 18 tries.**

Comment: I am curious why you ignored primes less than 10000000? Presumably initial zeros are just as likely?

Comment: True, I did not think of that case. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

In [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem) you can read about the distribution of primes. Below $99999999$, the largest $8$ digit number, the number of primes is approximately

$$\frac{99999999}{\ln(99999999)}\approx 5428680.
$$

The probability in question is then

$$\frac{5428680}{99999999}\approx0,05428681
.$$